# What are the packages required to install graphics in python idle

Tags: python, graphics

I am unable to find the vector graphic packages in python v3.9.

I tried the SimpleGraphics library but I am looking for more advanced libraries so can anyone suggest some best ones?

Comment: Recommendations are not in the scope of this site, sorry.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.